# How can I manipulate and run a remote SSIS package from VB Script?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, sql-server-2000

I have some old VB Script code that I can modify but I cannot migrate the app to a new language...

This VB Script basically used to connect to a SQL 2000 Server and manipulate the connections of the package before running it, which would output a flatfile database locally.

Now I do not have a DTS package, I just have an SSIS package.

The code used to be this:

```
dim DTScon
dim DTSpkg
set DTSpkg = Server.CreateObject("DTS.Package")
DTSpkg.LoadFromSQLServer "mysqlserver","myuser","mypass",dts.DTSSQLStgFlag_Default,,,,"MyPackageName"

set DTScon = DTSpkg.Connections.Item("Conn1")
set DTScon.UserId = "conn_username"
set DTScon.Password = "conn_password"
set DTScnp = DTScon.ConnectionProperties.Item("Data Source");
DTScnp.Value = "c:\path\to\output\flatfile"
```

I am now trying to modify the code to

```
dim DTScon
dim DTSpkg
set DTSpkg = Server.CreateObject("DTS.Application")
DTSpkg.LoadFromSQLServer "mysqlserver","myuser","mypass",dts.DTSSQLStgFlag_Default,,,,"MyPackageName"

set DTScon = DTSpkg.Connections.Item("Conn1")
set DTScon.UserId = "conn_username"
set DTScon.Password = "conn_password"
set DTScnp = DTScon.ConnectionProperties.Item("Data Source");
DTScnp.Value = "c:\path\to\output\flatfile"
```

First error I got is:
    Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01b6'
    Object doesn't support this property or mother: 'DTSpkg.LoadFromSQLServer'
    /main.asp.241

This I am guessing will be one of the many hurdles I will probably have to overcome.
However, I have struggled to find a solution to this by Google searching.

Has anyone got an idea of what I need to do to get IIS running this new code?
Or any problems I am likely to face trying to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option would be to change your SSIS packages to use Package Configurations for the Connection Managers.  If you use SQL Server configurations, when the package is loaded and executed, it will change the Connection Managers based on what it finds in the SQL Server configuration table.  So your steps would be to alter the data in that table, then start the packages - no direct manipulation of the packages is necessary.